# How can I make randomly generated floor with certain room pieces in python 3.3?

Tags: python, algorithm, random

I have 15 different looking rooms as the below image demonstrates and I'm trying to make a game that has floors which are randomly generated from those rooms in a way that two conditions are met:

1. By starting in an arbitrary room you can walk to any other arbitrary room. (Demonstrated by Hopefully not happening: right one)
2. The whole floor is closed and you can not find a way out of any room to the outside. (Demonstrated by Hopefully not happening: left one)

[image]

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more?

Comment: @MaskedMan Have you heard of a game called The binding of Isaac? If you have then it's fairly simple. I'm trying to create same kind of random floor mechanic. I really don't know what are the things you want to know more specified, but I can try if you haven't heard of that game.

Comment: @MaskedMan Okay great and thanks for editing it. Now it's so much more understandable :). I have never been good at explaining things in simple way...

Comment: I am happy that my editing made you happy :)

Comment: in your desired floor do every room have a door to any adjacent room?

Comment: @MaskedMan No (if I understood what you meant with that question). I can try to post the progress I have made this far if you want(?) The only thing I have left is the problem demonstrated in the right one of "Hopefully not happening".

Comment: So why would have you accepted the answer below if it isn't fully solved?
and by the question I meant that if you are in a room you can walk into any adjacent room that is a trivial path.
And is it foreknown how many rooms in row and column will the floor have?

Comment: Is [this image](http://pasteboard.co/6grAkfmJr.png) a valid floor?

Comment: @MaskedMan Of cource I haven't finished the code just yet. And I thought that because I'm getting it done I would accept the answer because then no one would answer if I kind of have the problem solved. Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way, simple and fast once you precalculated your tables:

As your drawing shows, you have only a finite set of possible rooms.
Each room has four sides.
On each side you can predetermine which rooms are acceptable as neighbor and store those in a table.
So four tables of possible neigbors per room.

```
'''
Each room has 4 sides: top, left, bottom, right. False means no door in that side, True means there's a door in that side.
iTop .. iRight are the indices of the sides.
The lists with numbers contain the indices of rooms that could be adjacent to a given room on that particular side.
So e.g rooms [0] can have rooms [0], rooms [3], rooms [5] and rooms [9] on its iTop side.
Note: I just use random indices in the example.
'''

iTop, iLeft, iBottom, iRight = range (4)

rooms = [
    [(False, [0, 3, 5, ...]), False, [0, 4, 7, ...], False, [0, 6, 11, ...], False, [0, 2, 7, ...]],
    [(True, [2, 7,....
]
```

From that set you select a random one.
The first room doesn't have any constraints.
In this way you make your 'building' grow room by room.

You prevent "empty" (I guess you mean non-existent) rooms by working systematically per row and then per column on a 2D grid.

To make this in Python 3.3 you need a graphics library.
If you want to keep it simple, the turtle module that comes with Python can easily handle this.

First get familiar with the turtle module using examples from the docs or the internet.

Then try to program what I just sketched.

Note that if you don't want any doors leading out of the building, that's just an extra constraint. If your building is square on each outside wall only certain rooms are permitted. Once again use a table per outside wall.

If it's only the graphics that you're after, you could get by much easier if each room only has a left and a top wall (which both could contain a door). Any room will then be acceptable as neighbor to any other room. Only the lowermost and rightmost rooms will have (closed) right and bottom walls.

But since you're writing a game, probably your rooms need four walls to be self-contained with respect to the game logic.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer and I will try to make it in the way you suggested. But the graphics engine/library that I'm using is pygame (I guess I should have mentioned it). But is there a way that you could make a small example of the table part because I have never used tables in programming and it would help quite a bit (of course I'm going to see some documents about using them as well).

Comment: See added example code

Comment: Thank you so much!